# How to find if a delete event on FileSystemWatcher was a file or a folder?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am using FileSystemWatcher to watch on a directory. On delete events I need to take different actions on files and folders. But I didn't find a way as the file/folder was already deleted.

One way can be to check if the file/folder path had any extension to it. but that's not a reliable way.

In Short I want to implement **WasFile()** method here ->

```
private static void OnDelete(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    if(WasFile(e.FullPath))
    {
          Console.WriteLine("Deleted event {0} was a File", e.FullPath);
    }
    //else a folder
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
if(e.FullPath[e.FullPath.Length]  == '\\')
{
    // directory
}
else
{
    //file
}
```

Or

```
if(Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
{
   // directory
}
else
{
    // file
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `...[...Length-1]`.

Comment: If I delete the folder. It became file according to the second logic